# why php input blank value or duplicate values in one form if submit another form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am encountering a strange phenomena: When I submit a form in my code, then beside doing what is there in that form, it looks like it also trigger the comment form. So when the page is reloading, I get some blank comments or duplicate comments. In my code I have several forms with submit, and one of that is the form for input comment:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="a" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="b" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ?>">
<input type="text" name="c" value="Name"><br>

<textarea name="d">
</textarea>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Could any of you point out for me where it gets wrong?

As requested, I post the whole (updated) code here:

```
<h3>Comments</h3>
<!-- <p>Put your comments here: </p> -->

<?php 
//a: commenters
$i  = addslashes($_POST['a']);
$ip = addslashes($_POST['b']);
$a  = addslashes($_POST['c']);
$b  = addslashes($_POST['d']);

if(isset($_POST['form1'])){

if(isset($i) & isset($ip) & isset($a) & isset($b))
{
    $connector= new DbConnector();
    $r = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `databasename`.`ban` WHERE ip=$ip"); //Check if banned
    $r = mysql_fetch_array($r);
    if(!$r[0]) //Phew, not banned
    {  // echo "a: ".$a." b: ".$b." ip: ".$ip." i: ".$i."";
            $Date4=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO `databasename`.`Comments` VALUES ('$a', '$b', '$ip', '$Date4')"))
        {
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.location="/index.php?id=".<?php echo $i; ?>;
            </script>
            <?php
        }
        else echo "Error, in mysql query";  
    }
    else echo "Error, You are banned.";
}

}
$x = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `databasename`.`Comments` ORDER BY i DESC ");
while($r = mysql_fetch_object($x)) echo "<div class='c'>".$r->a."<p>".$r->b."</p> </div>";


?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="a" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="b" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ?>">
    <input type="text" name="c" value="Name"><br>

    <textarea name="d">
    </textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="form1"  />
</form>
```

Comment: seams like you have a problem when you retrive the comments, This form seams valid. Do you have more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use `isset()`

in HTML submit button you need to use `name` attribute for each and every form,

```
<input type="submit" name="form1" />
```

IN PHP,

```
 <?php 

    if(isset($_POST['form1']){
          echo $_POST['a'];
    }

 ?>
```

Your code,

```
   <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">

   <input type="hidden" name="a" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="b" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>">
   <input type="text" name="c" value="Name"><br>

   <textarea name="d"></textarea>
   <input type="submit" name="form1"  />
   </form>
```

Comment: It looks like the solution for blank input case. But I don't know why I have many duplicate input sometimes. My guess is when I refresh the browser it bring the old input to input to the database (?) how to prevent that ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
 if(!empty($_POST['form1']){
          echo $_POST['a'];
    }
```

empty() will return true if the variable is an empty string, false, array(), NULL, “0?, 0, and an unset variable.

Read more: http://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/